# constraining the table against inserts or updates

Tags: php, postgresql

I am a newbie to PHP and PostgreSQL,,,,

I created a table with the following query,,,

```
CREATE TABLE public.affiliate (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(32),
  parent INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT affiliate_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Here, I have populated the table in such a way that id starts with 1 and the rest of the nodes are sequentially numbered and maximum number of depths are set to 10.

Now, I need to constrain the table against inserts or updates that would otherwise create cyclic hierarchies.
How can I do that ?

Comment: 1) I think you forgot to add `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES affiliate(id)` to the parent definition? 2) you could impose partial order : `check COALESCE(parent, id) < id`

Comment: You can't really protect against a cycle as the cycle could be at any level of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on auto generated identifiers for business purposes, this often leads to more problem than it solves. Regarding the constraint on modifying the table, you can have a look at the [rule system](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createrule.html).

It allows you to rewrite queries on the fly:

```
CREATE RULE prevent_insert AS 
  ON INSERT 
  TO public.affiliate 
  DO INSTEAD 
    NOTHING;
```

This will prevent insertions in the given table. Of course this does not behave exactly like a constraint as it does not raise an error hence does not invalidate transactions.